# Minilibx works slowly on M1 Pro

Tags: c, apple-m1, arm64

I'm trying to create a game with minilibx library and there are few issues with him. My game works very well on old iMac with Intel processor, but when I'm trying to run it on my M1 Pro MacBook it's works too slowly and you can see how it puts each picture on the window.
What you can suggest me to do?

[image]

I tried to use mlx_do_sync, but it's doesn't help.

Comment: You need to post a [MRE] if you want us to be able to help you.